# Printf - Controlling the output of a %.2f (float32)

Tags: c, printf, core-audio

I am logging out the raw data of an audio unit render callback in an xcode command line project.  I am getting the data from the iodata parameter and logging out the first "float32" bytes of information in these buffers like so:

```
   Float32 someDataL = *(Float32*)(player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData);
   Float32 someDataR = *(Float32*)(player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[1].mData);

   printf("L: %.2f || R: %.2f \n", someDataL,someDataR);
```

This question is about how to control the output of these buffers of memory in the console.  The data contained in the first float32 bytes of these buffers are 16bitdepth pcm audio samples and so range between -32768 and + 32768.  The output of my console than is erratic because sometimes there is a "-" sign and sometimes there is not.  IT therefore makes it hard for me to do my analysis because the log is shifting to the left and right.  For example

```
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: 0.00 || R: 0.00 
L: 0.00 || R: 0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00 
L: -0.00 || R: -0.00
```

Is there a way to control the width of the logs such that they are always equal?

Comment: This `player->inputBuffer->mBuffers` is ugly and dangerous!

Comment: `*(Float32*)...` is a good way to run into trouble. If you have a `float` buffer, make it `float`, but do not just reinterpret-cast.

Comment: i appreciate the constructive criticism but what is wrong with player->inputBuffer->mBuffers? its actually used all throughout the book i am reading.  for example, to initially allocate these buffers the code was 
for(UInt32 i =0; i< player->inputBuffer->mNumberBuffers ; i++) {
   player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1;
   player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = bufferSizeBytes;
   player->inputBuffer->mBuffers[i].mData = malloc(bufferSizeBytes);
  }

Comment: and as far as the float buffer goes, the buffer is defined as a void* field in the core audio struct that declares it.  i'm simply casting it to a float32 so C can dereference what lies in that memory.  there is no int, not float by default.  however, the audio stream is formatted to contain 16bit samples in float format.  so i'm simply trying to log out the raw data of the pcm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`printf(3)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html):

> ` ' (space)  A blank should be left before a positive number produced by a signed conversion (a, A, d, e, E, f, F, g, G, or i).

```
printf("L: % .2f || R: % .2f \n", someDataL,someDataR);
```

Comment: That will solve the sign problem, but it will not ensure *equal width*. Although this is an interesting answer.

Comment: actually this solved it.  the negative sign was the only change between logs.  Now I can begin to interpret this numbers which will be the hard part!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
printf("L: %6.2f || R: %6.2f \n", someDataL,someDataR);
//          ^           ^
//          |___________|_____ width modifier
```

or any sensible number as the width modifier.